# ES6 import function - execute in Vue component

Tags: function, vue.js, import

In my Vue app I have JS file with some config data. In JS file there is export function. I'm importing this function to my Vue component but it's returning function declaration as a string. How can I make that function to return it's return data?

JS file

```
export function Test(app) {
   return [ some data... ]
}
```

Vue component

```
import { Test } from '@/config/Test'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            testData: Test,
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see some code.

Comment: In your component you have a function called `Test` but you aren't calling it. You're just assigning the function to the property `testData`. If you then include that in your template as `{{ testData }}` the template will just call `toString` on it and you'll get the function source code. Somewhere along the line you need to call the function so it can return the data.

Comment: Yes I tried also putting testData to computed but result was the same...
Honestly I don't really need export function. I just need to import data. But to generate this data I need app instance because I need to return translated strings and I didn't find way how to pass app instance to export default variable.

Comment: The problem isn't that you're exporting a function, that seems perfectly sensible in the circumstances. The problem is that you aren't invoking the function. Call the function and you'll get your data. Easy. I can't show you how because I have no idea what `app` is.